# Solution to Diophantine equation $19991112x + 2803y = 33$

Tags: diophantine-equations, euclidean-algorithm

I already found that $gcd(19991112,2803)=1$ so it does have solution. But I don't know how to find the solution.

Equation: Diophantine equation $19991112x + 2803y = 33$

Comment: How did you find the GCD? Did you use the Euclidean algorithm? You can use the "extended Euclidean algorithm" to find solutions to equations like this. See e.g. https://brilliant.org/wiki/extended-euclidean-algorithm/ for examples and further reading.

Comment: The link is very useful. I found that $(9478483)2803 - (1329)19991112 = 1$

Comment: Solving for one variable yield $$y = -\frac{3 (6663704 x - 11)}{2803}$$
Testing $3000$ rows at a time yields the following sample $(x,y)$ pairs

$$(-10221,72896595)\quad (-7418,52905483)\quad (-4615,32914371)\\ (-1812,12923259)\quad (991,-7067853)\quad (3794,-27058965)\\ (6597,-47050077)\quad (9400,-67041189)\quad (12203,-87032301)\\ $$

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) you can find $a,b$ such that

$$19991112\cdot a + 2803\cdot b = 1.$$

In this case $a = (-1329), b = 9478483$. Therefore you can choose $$x=33\cdot a,y=33\cdot b.$$

Comment: The general solutions are:$x=2803 t-33\times 1329$, $y=-19991112 t+33\times 9478483$; t∈Z.

Answer (score 1):

meanwhile:

$$  \gcd( 19991112, 2803 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 19991112 }{ 2803 } = 7132 +  \frac{ 116 }{ 2803 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2803 }{ 116 } = 24 +  \frac{ 19 }{ 116 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 116 }{ 19 } = 6 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 19 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 19 }{ 2 } = 9 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 7132 & & 24 & & 6 & & 9 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 7132 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 171169 }{ 24 }   & &   \frac{ 1034146 }{ 145 }   & &   \frac{ 9478483 }{ 1329 }   & &   \frac{ 19991112 }{ 2803 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 19991112 \cdot 1329 - 2803 \cdot 9478483 = -1 $$